I have problem uploading files to minio bucket using python app
Problem Description:
I'm encountering an issue with file uploads to MinIO using Python code. When I upload files with the the Python script, the uploaded files appear in the MinIO bucket but have no size and cannot be opened. However, when I manually upload files, they are viewable and have a size.
What I've Tried:
Verified MinIO bucket settings: I have confirmed that the MinIO bucket settings are correct and that both manually uploaded files and files uploaded via the code are stored in the correct bucket.
Checked content type: I'm setting the content type correctly using the get_content_type() function to ensure that the uploaded files are recognized correctly.
Expected Outcome:
I expect that files uploaded via the Python script should be viewable and have a size, similar to manually uploaded files.
from minio import Minio
from minio.error import S3Error
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import FileField, SubmitField
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired
import mimetypes

minio_client = Minio(endpoint="play.min.io",
                     access_key="Q3AM3UQ867SPQQA43P2F",
                     secret_key="zuf+tfteSlswRu7BJ86wekitnifILbZam1KYY3TG")

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'supersecretkey'

class UploadFileForm(FlaskForm):
    file = FileField("File", validators=[InputRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Upload File")

def get_content_type(filename):
    content_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
    if not content_type:
        extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower()
        if extension in ('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif', '.bmp'):
            content_type = f'image/{extension.lstrip(".")}'
    return content_type or 'application/octet-stream'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    form = UploadFileForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        file = form.file.data
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        bucket_name = "saving-files" 
        try:
            
            content_type = get_content_type(filename)

            minio_client.put_object(bucket_name, filename, file, file.content_length, content_type=content_type)
            return "File has been uploaded to MinIO."
        except S3Error as e:
            return f"Error uploading file to MinIO: {e}"

    return render_template('index.html', form=form)

@app.route('/files/<filename>', methods=['GET'])
def get_file(filename):
    bucket_name = "saving-files"  
    try:
        file_data = minio_client.get_object(bucket_name, filename)
        return send_file(file_data, attachment_filename=filename)
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error retrieving file from MinIO: {e}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)



You are not reading the file from the request.FILES.
# read the file data
file_data = request.FILES[form.file.name].read()
# pass the file data to the `client.put_object`
minio_client.put_object(bucket_name, filename, file_data, file.content_length, content_type=content_type)

https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.FileField

That could true, but my main problem other than this is that the files that being uploaded to minio aren't being sent correctly, they are being shown corrupted.
